# How to write iterative cumulative sums of characters in R?

Tags: r, function, apply, cumsum

i am writing a model codes with this model specification below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCrE.png)

This model contains cumulative sums of lambdas as N increases (n=1~15).

The model that I specified is like below:

```
    jcode <- "model{ 
    for (i in 1:length(N)){
    n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
    seropos_est[i] = ifelse(age[i]>1 && age[i]<20, 1-exp(-2.5*lambda1)
       ,ifelse(age[i]>20 && age[i]<40, 1-exp(-(5*lambda1+2.5*lambda2)),
       ifelse(age[i]>40 && age[i]<60, 1-exp(-(5*lambda1+5*lambda2+2.5*lambda3)),
       1-exp(-(5*lambda1+5*lambda2+5*lambda3+2.5*lambda4)))))
    # time-varying catalytic model
    }

    #  prior dists
  lambda1 ~ dunif(0,1)       #uninformative prior
  lambda2 ~ dunif(0,1)       #uninformative prior
  lambda3 ~ dunif(0,1)       #uninformative prior
  lambda4 ~ dunif(0,1)       #uninformative prior

}"
```

However, I want to make the above equation divided into 15 different age groups with each group having cumulative sums of lambdas until (n-1).

Instead of iteratively writing down 5*lambda1+5*lambda2+5*lambda3 .....+ 5*lambda14 and so on, is there any way that I can sum up the 14 lambdas at once?

One way I considered was to store lambdas into a list and then sum up the lambdalist[1:2], lambdalist[1:3] .... lambdalist[1:14] but this doesn't work since elements inside the list are all character values, not numerical values.

I would like to reduce the iterative codes but I don't know how to specify the cumulative sums over the 15 age groups as in the model specification in the picture.

Also, is there a way that I can reduce the codes rather than using "if" function for the calculation in each age group??

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have code in a character string?

Comment: I have to run Rjags model, and that is I have to specify the model first before running it